# STM32F7: hard fault when jumping to application from custom bootloader

Tags: c, assembly, linker, arm, bootloader

I'm working on a Nucleo-F767zi board (stm32F767ZIT6U MCU) with custom bootloader and application in Atollic TrueSTUDIO. I have working bootloader and application. I have started both separately without errors. But when I try to run application from bootloader I have hard_fault in application. Image of application is correct (address, size and check code of image are valid) before I jump. I would appreciate for any idea of what I should pay attention and remake.

part of bootloader code:

```
int boot_main(void)
{
  // Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick.
  HAL_Init();

  // Configure the system clock
  SystemClock_Config();

  // bootloader
  if (isBootFlag() || checkMainAppWithSign()) {
    //HAL_DeInit();
    startMainApp();
  }

  // Initialize all configured peripherals
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_ETH_Init();
  MX_USART3_UART_Init();

  MX_USB_DEVICE_Init();

  createTask(&sysTaskControlBlock, threadTaskSystem, NULL, tskIDLE_PRIORITY + 3, bufferTaskSystem, sizemas(bufferTaskSystem), "SystemTask");
  // Start scheduler */
  osKernelStart();
  // We should never get here as control is now taken by the scheduler
  // Infinite loop
  while (1) {

  }
}

void startMainApp(void)
{
  uint32_t mainAppAddr;
  mainAppAddr =  (uint32_t)Flash_Get_Starting_Address(FLASH_SPACE_APPLICATION);

  __disable_irq();

  typedef void(*pMainApp)(void);
  pMainApp mainApplication;
  mainApplication = (pMainApp)(mainAppAddr + 4);
  __set_MSP(*(uint32_t*)mainAppAddr);

  SCB->VTOR = mainAppAddr;

  mainApplication();
}
```

bootloader linker script:

```
/* Entry Point */
ENTRY(Boot_Reset_Handler)

/* Highest address of the user mode stack */
_estack = 0x20080000;    /* end of RAM */

/* Generate a link error if heap and stack don't fit into RAM */
_Min_Heap_Size = 0;      /* required amount of heap  */
_Min_Stack_Size = 0x400; /* required amount of stack */

/* Specify the memory areas */
MEMORY
{
  /* Single bank mode */
  FLASH_LOADER(rx)         : ORIGIN = 0x08000000,                      LENGTH = 96K                  /* 32K   * 3 sectors*/
  FLASH_SIGN(rx)           : ORIGIN = 0x08000000 + 96K,                LENGTH = 32K                  /* 32K   * 1 sector*/
  FLASH_USER_DATA(rx)      : ORIGIN = 0x08000000 + 96K + 32K,          LENGTH = 128K                 /* 128K  * 1 sector*/
  FLASH_MAIN_APP(rx)       : ORIGIN = 0x08000000 + 128K + 128K,        LENGTH = 512K                 /* 256K  * 2 sector*/

  DTCMRAM (xrw)   : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 128K
  SRAM1 (xrw)     : ORIGIN = 0x20020000, LENGTH = 368K - 32
  SRAM1_FLAG (xrw): ORIGIN = 0x20020000 + 368K - 32, LENGTH = 32
  SRAM2 (xrw)     : ORIGIN = 0x2007C000, LENGTH = 16K
  MEMORY_B1 (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x60000000, LENGTH = 0K
}

REGION_ALIAS("FLASH", FLASH_LOADER)

__flash_sign__             = ORIGIN(FLASH_SIGN);
__flash_sign_end__         = __flash_user_data__ + LENGTH(FLASH_SIGN);
__flash_user_data__        = ORIGIN(FLASH_USER_DATA);
__flash_user_data_end__    = __flash_user_data__ + LENGTH(FLASH_USER_DATA);
__flash_main_app__         = ORIGIN(FLASH_MAIN_APP);
__flash_main_app_end__     = __flash_main_app__ + LENGTH(FLASH_MAIN_APP);

__ram_bootflag__           = ORIGIN(SRAM1_FLAG);

/* Define output sections */
SECTIONS
{
  /* The startup code goes first into FLASH */
  .isr_vector :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector)) /* Startup code */
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH

  /* The program code and other data goes into FLASH */
  .text :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.text)           /* .text sections (code) */
    *(.text*)          /* .text* sections (code) */
    *(.glue_7)         /* glue arm to thumb code */
    *(.glue_7t)        /* glue thumb to arm code */
    *(.eh_frame)

    KEEP (*(.init))
    KEEP (*(.fini))

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _etext = .;        /* define a global symbols at end of code */
  } >FLASH

  /* Constant data goes into FLASH */
  .rodata :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.rodata)         /* .rodata sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    *(.rodata*)        /* .rodata* sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH

  .ARM.extab   : { *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*) } >FLASH
  .ARM : {
    __exidx_start = .;
    *(.ARM.exidx*)
    __exidx_end = .;
  } >FLASH

  .preinit_array     :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH
  .init_array :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH
  .fini_array :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.fini_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH

  /* used by the startup to initialize data */
  _sidata = LOADADDR(.data);

  /* Initialized data sections goes into RAM, load LMA copy after code */
  .data : 
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sdata = .;        /* create a global symbol at data start */
    *(.data)           /* .data sections */
    *(.data*)          /* .data* sections */

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _edata = .;        /* define a global symbol at data end */
  } >SRAM1 AT> FLASH

  _sidtcmram = LOADADDR(.dtcmram);

  /* DTCMRAM section 
  * 
  * IMPORTANT NOTE! 
  * If initialized variables will be placed in this section, 
  * the startup code needs to be modified to copy the init-values.  
  */
  .dtcmram :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sdtcmram = .;       /* create a global symbol at dtcmram start */
    *(.dtcmram)
    *(.dtcmram*)

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _edtcmram = .;       /* create a global symbol at dtcmram end */
  } >DTCMRAM AT> FLASH

 _sisram2 = LOADADDR(.sram2);

  /* SRAM2 section 
  * 
  * IMPORTANT NOTE! 
  * If initialized variables will be placed in this section, 
  * the startup code needs to be modified to copy the init-values.  
  */
  .sram2 :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _ssram2 = .;       /* create a global symbol at sram2 start */
    *(.sram2)
    *(.sram2*)

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _esram2 = .;       /* create a global symbol at sram2 end */
  } >SRAM2 AT> FLASH


  /* Uninitialized data section */
  . = ALIGN(4);
  .bss :
  {
    /* This is used by the startup in order to initialize the .bss secion */
    _sbss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss start */
    __bss_start__ = _sbss;
    *(.bss)
    *(.bss*)
    *(COMMON)

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _ebss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss end */
    __bss_end__ = _ebss;
  } >SRAM1

  /* User_heap_stack section, used to check that there is enough SRAM1 left */
  ._user_heap_stack :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    PROVIDE ( end = . );
    PROVIDE ( _end = . );
    . = . + _Min_Heap_Size;
    . = . + _Min_Stack_Size;
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >SRAM1

  /* MEMORY_bank1 section, code must be located here explicitly            */
  /* Example: extern int foo(void) __attribute__ ((section (".mb1text"))); */
  .memory_b1_text :
  {
    *(.mb1text)        /* .mb1text sections (code) */
    *(.mb1text*)       /* .mb1text* sections (code)  */
    *(.mb1rodata)      /* read-only data (constants) */
    *(.mb1rodata*)
  } >MEMORY_B1

  /* Remove information from the standard libraries */
  /DISCARD/ :
  {
    libc.a ( * )
    libm.a ( * )
    libgcc.a ( * )
  }

  .ARM.attributes 0 : { *(.ARM.attributes) }
}
```

application linker script:

```
/* Entry Point */
ENTRY(Reset_Handler)

/* Highest address of the user mode stack */
_estack = 0x20080000;    /* end of RAM */

/* Generate a link error if heap and stack don't fit into RAM */
_Min_Heap_Size = 0;      /* required amount of heap  */
_Min_Stack_Size = 0x400; /* required amount of stack */

/* Specify the memory areas */
MEMORY
{
  /* Single bank mode */
  FLASH_LOADER(rx)         : ORIGIN = 0x08000000,                      LENGTH = 96K                  /* 32K   * 3 sectors*/
  FLASH_SIGN(rx)           : ORIGIN = 0x08000000 + 96K,                LENGTH = 32K                  /* 32K   * 1 sector*/
  FLASH_USER_DATA(rx)      : ORIGIN = 0x08000000 + 96K + 32K,          LENGTH = 128K                 /* 128K  * 1 sector*/
  FLASH_MAIN_APP(rx)       : ORIGIN = 0x08000000 + 128K + 128K,        LENGTH = 512K                 /* 256K  * 2 sector*/

  DTCMRAM (xrw)   : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 128K
  SRAM1 (xrw)     : ORIGIN = 0x20020000, LENGTH = 368K - 32
  SRAM1_FLAG (xrw): ORIGIN = 0x20020000 + 368K - 32, LENGTH = 32
  SRAM2 (xrw)     : ORIGIN = 0x2007C000, LENGTH = 16K
  MEMORY_B1 (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x60000000, LENGTH = 0K
}

REGION_ALIAS("FLASH", FLASH_MAIN_APP)

__flash_sign__             = ORIGIN(FLASH_SIGN);
__flash_sign_end__         = __flash_user_data__ + LENGTH(FLASH_SIGN);
__flash_user_data__        = ORIGIN(FLASH_USER_DATA);
__flash_user_data_end__    = __flash_user_data__ + LENGTH(FLASH_USER_DATA);
__flash_main_app__         = ORIGIN(FLASH_MAIN_APP);
__flash_main_app_end__     = __flash_main_app__ + LENGTH(FLASH_MAIN_APP);

__ram_bootflag__           = ORIGIN(SRAM1_FLAG);

/* Define output sections */
SECTIONS
{
  /* The startup code goes first into FLASH */
  .isr_vector :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    KEEP(*(.isr_vector)) /* Startup code */
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH

  /* The program code and other data goes into FLASH */
  .text :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.text)           /* .text sections (code) */
    *(.text*)          /* .text* sections (code) */
    *(.glue_7)         /* glue arm to thumb code */
    *(.glue_7t)        /* glue thumb to arm code */
    *(.eh_frame)

    KEEP (*(.init))
    KEEP (*(.fini))

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _etext = .;        /* define a global symbols at end of code */
  } >FLASH

  /* Constant data goes into FLASH */
  .rodata :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    *(.rodata)         /* .rodata sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    *(.rodata*)        /* .rodata* sections (constants, strings, etc.) */
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >FLASH

  .ARM.extab   : { *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*) } >FLASH
  .ARM : {
    __exidx_start = .;
    *(.ARM.exidx*)
    __exidx_end = .;
  } >FLASH

  .preinit_array     :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.preinit_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__preinit_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH
  .init_array :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.init_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.init_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__init_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH
  .fini_array :
  {
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_start = .);
    KEEP (*(SORT(.fini_array.*)))
    KEEP (*(.fini_array*))
    PROVIDE_HIDDEN (__fini_array_end = .);
  } >FLASH

  /* used by the startup to initialize data */
  _sidata = LOADADDR(.data);

  /* Initialized data sections goes into RAM, load LMA copy after code */
  .data : 
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sdata = .;        /* create a global symbol at data start */
    *(.data)           /* .data sections */
    *(.data*)          /* .data* sections */

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _edata = .;        /* define a global symbol at data end */
  } >SRAM1 AT> FLASH

  _sidtcmram = LOADADDR(.dtcmram);

  /* DTCMRAM section 
  * 
  * IMPORTANT NOTE! 
  * If initialized variables will be placed in this section, 
  * the startup code needs to be modified to copy the init-values.  
  */
  .dtcmram :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _sdtcmram = .;       /* create a global symbol at dtcmram start */
    *(.dtcmram)
    *(.dtcmram*)

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _edtcmram = .;       /* create a global symbol at dtcmram end */
  } >DTCMRAM AT> FLASH

 _sisram2 = LOADADDR(.sram2);

  /* SRAM2 section 
  * 
  * IMPORTANT NOTE! 
  * If initialized variables will be placed in this section, 
  * the startup code needs to be modified to copy the init-values.  
  */
  .sram2 :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _ssram2 = .;       /* create a global symbol at sram2 start */
    *(.sram2)
    *(.sram2*)

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _esram2 = .;       /* create a global symbol at sram2 end */
  } >SRAM2 AT> FLASH


  /* Uninitialized data section */
  . = ALIGN(4);
  .bss :
  {
    /* This is used by the startup in order to initialize the .bss secion */
    _sbss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss start */
    __bss_start__ = _sbss;
    *(.bss)
    *(.bss*)
    *(COMMON)

    . = ALIGN(4);
    _ebss = .;         /* define a global symbol at bss end */
    __bss_end__ = _ebss;
  } >SRAM1

  /* User_heap_stack section, used to check that there is enough SRAM1 left */
  ._user_heap_stack :
  {
    . = ALIGN(4);
    PROVIDE ( end = . );
    PROVIDE ( _end = . );
    . = . + _Min_Heap_Size;
    . = . + _Min_Stack_Size;
    . = ALIGN(4);
  } >SRAM1

  /* MEMORY_bank1 section, code must be located here explicitly            */
  /* Example: extern int foo(void) __attribute__ ((section (".mb1text"))); */
  .memory_b1_text :
  {
    *(.mb1text)        /* .mb1text sections (code) */
    *(.mb1text*)       /* .mb1text* sections (code)  */
    *(.mb1rodata)      /* read-only data (constants) */
    *(.mb1rodata*)
  } >MEMORY_B1

  /* Remove information from the standard libraries */
  /DISCARD/ :
  {
    libc.a ( * )
    libm.a ( * )
    libgcc.a ( * )
  }

  .ARM.attributes 0 : { *(.ARM.attributes) }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're `__set_MSP`ing to a flash address instead of a RAM address.

Comment: I checked MSP once more and see the same value - 0x20080000 at address 0x8040000. So, first reg of application vector table points to the highest RAM before application runs.

Answer (score 2):

I found my error. Thanks to Fiddling Bits who gave me useful hint. 
Working code for my application:

```
void startMainApp(void)
{
  typedef void(*pMainApp)(void);
  pMainApp mainApplication;

  uint32_t mainAppAddr =  (uint32_t)Flash_Get_Starting_Address(FLASH_SPACE_APPLICATION);
  uint32_t mainAppStack = (uint32_t)*((uint32_t*)mainAppAddr);
  mainApplication = (pMainApp)*(uint32_t*)(mainAppAddr + 4); // Corrected!!!

  __disable_irq();
  __set_MSP(mainAppStack);
  SCB->VTOR = mainAppAddr;
  __enable_irq();

  mainApplication();
}
```